# Как установить размер ячейки ниже 50 в QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Как установить размер ячейки ниже **`50`** в `QTableWidget`? Я попробовал установить минимальный размер по ширине и высоте методом : `setMinimumWidth` и `setMinimumHeight` *( это то, что я нашёл в документации)* но это не сработало.

То есть чтобы все ячейки помещались в таблице без образования скроллбара.

Пример кода:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 380, 345))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(20)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumWidth(1) # < --- 
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumHeight(1) # < --- то что я пытался сделать
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(17)

        for i in range(10):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(i, (63 if i in [0, 4, 8, 9] else 21))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: assert, объясните пожалуйста лучше что вы хотите сделать. Вы хотите уменьшить высоту строки? Если да, то какую высоту строки вы хотите установить?

Comment: Я хочу установить ширину рядов ниже 50 а именно 44 , а высоту строк 17. Тоесть чтобы все ячейк помещались в таблице без образования скролл бара

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(405, 400)                                    # + 405
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 400, 345))   # + 400
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(20)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        
# ???        self.tableWidget.setMinimumWidth(1) # < --- 
# ???        self.tableWidget.setMinimumHeight(1) # < --- то что я пытался сделать
        
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(17)
        
        for i in range(10):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(i, (63 if i in [0, 4, 8, 9] else 21))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(0, i, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))

        for row in range(20):            
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 5))                    # +++ <---- 5
    
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как сделать не меняя шрифт ?

Comment: @assert ,  вы спросили, как сделать чтобы все ячейки помещались в таблице без образования скролл бара, я вам предоставил вариант как это можно сделать. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю подойдет ли вам, мне в аналогичной задаче помог метод `setRowHeight()`, в котором можно указать произвольную высоту ячейки.

```
a = self.table1.rowCount()
self.table1.insertRow(a)
self.table1.setItem(a, 0, QTableWidgetItem(material))
self.table1.setRowHeight(a, 25) # устанавливаем произвольную высоту строки
```

P.S. в моем случае высота меняется после добавления элемента. Если вдруг кто то знает как это задать сразу для всего QTableWidget, в QT Designer, прошу отписаться в комментарии